# How can I pass a condition to a MIN statement in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, min

I've got a table with the following columns

```
email, id, date
```

There's a unique key on email+id, so the table can contain multiples of an email address. id can be null.

I want to return results in the format

```
email, first date, number of ids, first id date (if number of ids not null)
```

or

```
dave@myfirm.con, 2013-06-11, 0, NULL
alan@myfirm.con, 2013-06-12, 2, 2013-06-13
```

My query is pretty close to what I want, while still being efficient.

```
SELECT TOP (@rows * @page) email, MIN([date]) as [date],COUNT(id) as [ids],
[x] = CASE COUNT(id) WHEN 0 THEN NULL ELSE MIN([date]) END
FROM Table 
GROUP BY email ORDER by MIN([date])
```

However, this version of the query returns the overall MIN(date) for each email, if they have any entries with a non null `id`

Is there some way I can nullify the MIN(date) if there's no id? I'm working on a solution that adds a large number of days to `date` if id is 0 and getting the MIN of this, but it seems like there must be a smarter way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want a conditional `min()`, so use `case` inside the `min()`:

```
SELECT TOP (@rows * @page) email,
       MIN([date]) as [date],
       COUNT(id) as [ids],
       min(case when id is not null then [date] end) as [x]
FROM Table 
GROUP BY email
ORDER by MIN([date])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT TOP (@rows * @page) email, MIN([date]) as [date],COUNT(id) as [ids],
[x] = (SELECT MIN([date]) FROM table t2 WHERE t2.email = t.email and t2.id IS NOT NULL) 
FROM Table t
GROUP BY email ORDER by MIN([date])
```

Comment: Sure -- whether it's a measurable performance hit depends entirely on your data model and how many records we're talking about though.  ;)